# Can we send message to all registered user with Android GCM?

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I am using android GCM for sending push notification to all registered users but i am not able to send the message to all the registered users at once instead i have to write message separately for each user.So can this be replaced in such a way that on single click message is sent to all the users stored in database?? I am using PHP Script for this(Server Side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send you message to all of your users, however you just can't broadcast it to all of them at once. Instead you have to send your message in groups of up to 1000 registration IDs and use the JSON request format.

More information can be found here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#request

Specifically:

> **registration_ids** - A string array with the list of devices
>   (registration IDs) receiving the message. It must contain at least 1
>   and at most 1000 registration IDs. To send a multicast message, you
>   must use JSON. For sending a single message to a single device, you
>   could use a JSON object with just 1 registration id, or plain text
>   (see below). Required.

Here is their example that sends data to six fictional registration IDs:

```
{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

Comment: Thanx Selsine. I tried this and it works but here in the above code you have manually entered the registration ids but i want this to be done dynamically. I want to pass n number of ids probably less than 1000,to the "registration_ids".So can u help me in this??? I am using PHP.

Comment: You simply need to loop through your database of registration IDs, add them to an array up to N, and then write them out into your JSON request.

Comment: Its working. You just need to pass the array of registration ids.